# Getting SSID and BSSID from a file in efficent way

Tags: c++, string, performance

I have file called Network.txt which will have SSID and BSSID as below

```
SSID                              BSSID               MODE             FREQ       RATE       SIGNAL   SECURITY   ACTIVE
'Bards Tale'                  30:DA:9B:70:EE:F4   Infrastructure   2412  MHz   54 MB/s    47       WPA2              no
'Alaskan Pale'                70:37:73:B7:3A:53   Infrastructure   2412 MHz   54 MB/s    44       WPA2             yes
'Abita Turbodog'              9C:1E:04:4C:59:FC   Infrastructure   2412 MHz   54 MB/s    7        WPA WPA2         no
'Alaskan Amber'               12:62:EB:2C:C0:06   Infrastructure   2422 MHz   54 MB/s    2        WPA WPA2         no
~
```

I want to get SSID and BSSID in safe and efficient way below is my approach which is working fine but can it be improve ?

```
  void GetSSIDAndBSSID(const std::string &temp)
    {
        if (temp.find("'") != std::string::npos)
        {

            std::string::size_type end_pos = temp.find_last_of(":");
            if (end_pos == std::string::npos)
                end_pos = temp.size();

     std::string FirstWord = temp.substr(1, end_pos+2); 
    std::cout <<"SSID="<< FirstWord.substr(0,temp.find_last_of("'")-1) << std::endl;
   std::cout<<"BSSID=" << FirstWord.substr(temp.find_first_of(":")-2,temp.find_last_of(":")+2) << std::endl;
        }
    }


int main()
{
        ifstream fin("pathTO/Network.txt");
        std::string line;
        while(getline(fin,line))
        {

                GetSSIDAndBSSID(line);

        }
```

Can this code be improved ?

Comment: yes, for example so that it actually compiles.

Comment: I think this code may be improved by using regular expressions

Comment: Plus mapped file and string_view, this remove unnecessary heap allocations.

Comment: Your post  in its current form is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the section [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you want assistance improving existing _working_ code I suggest you check out [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).